# How to call a function inside a XULRunner browser control?

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, xulrunner

I'm trying to send parameters to a javascript function embedded in the browser page but with no luck

This is the page script:

```
    window.loadfile = function(filename){
        dump(filename+" loaded");
    };
```

I have tried changing the location to javascript:loadfile() but apparently this does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok, I managed to solve this using messages and directly accesing through contentWindow and contentDocument which is even easier:

```
document.getElementById("mybrowser").contentWindow.readfile("file.txt");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_message_manager